# OTS Error for Black Future Font in React Application

Tags: fonts, css, web-fonts

I am encountering a perplexing issue with the Black Future font in my React application and am seeking assistance to resolve it. Below, I have detailed the problem, my troubleshooting efforts, and specific questions.

**Issue Description:**

I am trying to use the Black Future font, obtained from [this source](https://www.dafontfree.io/black-future-font/), in a React application. The font loads without issues in online font checkers and in Canva. However, when I attempt to load it in my React app, it fails with an OTS parsing error. This error occurs across all font file types (WOFF2, WOFF, TTF, OTF) and in all browsers except Safari (which I haven't tested).

**Error Message:**

`OTS parsing error: failed to parse table`

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

1. Verified that the font loads correctly in other environments (online checkers, Canva).
2. Attempted to use various font formats (WOFF2, WOFF, TTF, OTF) in the application.
3. Used FontForge to try and recreate the font with some tweaks. During this, I noticed that the asterisk character has an overlap issue, but I'm unsure if this is related to the parsing error in the browser.
4. Tested the font in multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) with the same error.

**Additional Information:**

- Font type: Black Future (TrueType/OpenType).
- Operating System: Windows 11
- Browsers tested: Chrome, Firefox, Edge (error in all, haven't tested Safari).

**Specific Questions:**

1. Could the overlap issue in the asterisk character be causing the OTS parsing error in browsers?
2. Are there any known compatibility issues with the Black Future font in web applications, specifically React?
3. What tools or methods can I use to further diagnose or fix this font file?
4. Would anyone be willing to assist in modifying or fixing the font file so it can be used in a React application?

Comment: React questions seem better suited to http://StackOverflow.com. Anytime one feels the need to mention what OS they are using.. the question is typically off topic.

Comment: I think it has more to do with the font itself, I was just including as much detail as possible. I dont really have experience working extensively with fonts. usually i just download and use them.

Comment: Have you tried loading a different font file of the same type(s)?